# What is Apache Maven and how do i install Geomesa-FS in my Ubuntu 20.04 through Apache maven?

Tags: maven, geomesa

I am completely new to spatiotemporal data analysis and I saw geomesa providing all the functionality that I need in my project.
Lets say i have a pd dataframe or an SQL server with all the location data like

- latitude
- longitude
- shopid

and

- latitude
- longitude
- customerid
- timestamp

Now Geomesa will help me analysis all nearest shops to a customer on their route and weather to show an ad of that shop to the customer. (To my knowledge)(Assuming other data required)
Finding Popular shops and etc.

In installation documentation of geomesa it requires to install Apache Maven which i did by

```
sudo apt install maven
```

[Image of maven version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef7bQ.png)

now there are a lot of of options for running geomesa.

- Is geomesa only for distributed systems?
- Is it even possible for using geomesa in my problem?
- Is it a dependency?
- Can i use it through python?

Also can you suggest me best choice of database for spatiotemporal data.

I downloaded geomesa-fs since i don't have any distributed property to my data.
But don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeoMesa is mainly used with distributed systems, but not always. Take a look at the [introduction](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/introduction.html) in the documentation for more details. For choosing a database, take a look at the [Getting Started](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/getting_started.html) page. Python is mainly [supported](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/spark/pyspark.html) through PySpark. Maven is only required for building from the source code, which you generally would not need to do.

If you already have your data in MySQL, you may just want to use [GeoTools](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/build/index.html) and [GeoServer](https://docs.geoserver.org/), which support MySQL.